# Weird GLSL error with textures, why do I get an invalid operation when running a shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures

I have a simple *GLSL 1.2* shader which accumulates values from five textures. 
The shader compiles just fine.
My problem is , when rendering a simple triangle with this shader activated, nothing gets drawn, and `glGetError()` returns invalid operation.

However, if I only utilize three of the textures, everything runs just fine. If I activate another shader before rendering the triangle, everything runs fine aswell.

Seems like there is something about textures and shaders I don't seem to know, any ideas on why I would get an invalid operation from running a shader?

*Update:*

- The problems occurs on both Nvidia, ATI and software MESA rendering.
- There are no glErrors while uploading textures, activating textures, activating the shader, setting uniforms to the shader, the gl error occurs after rendering one simple triangle.
- The textures are accesed only in the fragment shader.

Comment: Please always mention your target OpenGL version

Comment: Please verify which command sets `glGetError`, can't say much without this. The OpenGL docs say exactly when a specific error is reported by a given command, so that will probably narrow the problem to a few cases.

Comment: In what stage you are accessing textures? In the fragment shader?

Answer (score 1):

There is a limited number of  textures you can use in a shader.

The limit is specific of vertex stage, fragment stage and an overall combined limit.

With the most probability, you are exceeding this limit. The limit is system-dependent, indeed you have to query that limits by using glGet routines with the following parameters:

- GL_MAX_{VERTEX|FRAGMENT}_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS for specific shader stage
- GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS for an entire shader program

if more than one of the vertex or fragment stage access the same texture unit, each access counts separately against GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS.

Comment: But can it be as low as five textures?

Comment: @ViktorSehr: It depends on the hardware. Vertex shaders on pre-DX10 hardware couldn't be expected to access more than 4.

Comment: Must be something else, GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS returns 96 and GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS returns 32. (GL_MAX_FRAGMENT_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS does not exist)

Comment: @ViktorSehr: What hardware are you running?

Comment: The value of GL_MAX_FRAGMENT_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS is 0x8872. Define it yourself or update your headers, then query the value. Maybe it is defined by the symbol GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS (it has the very same value).

Comment: What is the value of MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS?